# Change a block type in InnerBlocks template without losing content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a block type that contains other blocks using InnerBlocks, with the output generated by an InnerBlocks template (similar to the columns core block). I want to be able to change one of the blocks to another block type, (one that has the transform defined), but when I do, the content gets erased.

Is there a way to do this?

By way of analogy, if the core columns block had sub-blocks "column-third" and "column-half", would there be a way of changing from two "column-half"s to three "column-third"s without losing the data?

To expand on the above analogy, suppose I made clones of the core [columns](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/columns/index.js) and [column](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/columns/column.js) blocks, and I modify the columns block like so:

The template generation function:

```
var childBlockName = 'core/column';
const getColumnsTemplate = memoize( ( columns ) => {
    return times( columns, () => [ childBlockName ] );
} );
```

and the RangeControl in the edit function:

```
<RangeControl
    label={ __( 'Columns' ) }
    value={ columns }
    onChange={ ( nextColumns ) => {
        childBlockName = 'coreclone/column';
        setAttributes( {
            columns: nextColumns,
        } );
    } }
    min={ 2 }
    max={ 6 }
/>
```

core/column and coreclone/column are identical. In this example, when I change the number of columns, the child block-type changes in the template. The core/column blocks don't get converted to coreclone/column blocks, they just get wiped and new coreclone/column blocks are made. I would like them to be transformed to coreclone/column blocks without the contents being wiped.

Comment: Are you using `<InnerBlocks.Content/>` in your save function?

Comment: Yes. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Currently you question is very ambiguous so please provide some screenshots and code samples that explains your problem.